# Is there a way in typescript to force a class to implement/override a static variable?

Tags: angular, typescript

Is there a way in typescript to force a class to implement/override a static variable?

**Use Case:**
I want the users to be able to select a component from a list of components. I will then show the user a preview of the component they selected.
I want the component class itself to have a `widgetName` static property so that I can use this static property in the listing of components.

**What I tried so far:**
I created an abstract class, which every component in the list will extend

```
export abstract class WidgetComponent {
  static widgetName: string;
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-widget-one',
  templateUrl: './widget-one.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./widget-one.component.scss'],
})
export class WidgetOneComponent extends WidgetComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() {
    super();
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

}
```

**Issue with the current approach:**
There is a `widgetName` static property present in every component but these components are not forced to override this `widgetName` property.

Once again, is there some way to force a class to implement/override a static variable?

Comment: I think you mean *static property*, rather than *static variable*.

Answer (score 2):

You can't have abstract static members, and you can't have abstract data properties. :-|

I see a three options, of which I think I like the third the most (but I started out with just two, so I added it to the end):

1. Make it an abtract prototype function that returns the widget name.
2. Make it an abstract prototype getter (accessor function) that returns the widget name. You access this just like a data property, but it's a hidden function call.
3. Make the type of the component a union of a base class and `{widgetName: string;}`.

Of the first two, the second makes it slightly more obvious that the function is expected not to do any significant work.

```typescript
abstract class WidgetComponent {
    abstract get widgetName(): string;
}

class Example extends WidgetComponent {
    get widgetName() { return "example"; }
}

// Works, but I don't like it -- note you have to look at the prototype
console.log(Example.prototype.widgetName); // "example;
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/IYIwzgLgTsDGEAJYBthjAg6gSwCYHMBTCAYQHsBbABzIDtDbEBvAKAXYVEhngSMQDuefgDlgFQgAoAlAC4E3bLXwBuFgF8WLFGgwBRAB7iqyQgkIGIDXBhwFi5anQbM2HfgiH2IYiTIRMCFDEAK5QtAgARBbGppEqCJqaLAD0KVhkUADWYAA0CCAhiACSCLh0AOSIyNhZZtiIALSNCLRkVggAnmQhCAAWwABuZhBkCMhkZFmciBB9ZlRQ7e2dVITadGBkpgB0E-iShrGEO4vLEKsnXqLihNIJaVEx1KYqQA)

Or here's an example of #3:

```typescript
abstract class BaseWidgetComponent {
}

type WidgetComponent = BaseWidgetComponent & {widgetName: string;};

class Good extends BaseWidgetComponent {
    static widgetName = "good";
}

class Bad extends BaseWidgetComponent {
}

console.log(Good.widgetName); // <== Works
console.log(Bad.widgetName);  // <== Fails
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=15&pc=1#code/IYIwzgLgTsDGEAJYBthjAgQmgpgdQEsATAcxwgGEB7AWwAcqA7HRxAbwCgBfDjiATzo4EhUuWr0mLRAF4suUWUq0GzVggBkCNgHdiSgHLAaOAFwJIUAoxIBuLrd4o0GAOJUqRBDgAeEFkQY2GD4+uIqUuqcCDEWEMAQBLAIemIQRiYIcgBEJB5E2Y48HM7o8l6+-oyB8iGK4ZJq7NxOTGBUyDgAdMhUJAAU7p5dqYbGOACUtggA9DMIADwycnhUUADWYCVtHd29A9hEI2Hp41Mxc4vLCABiwATIW0A)

Comment: 1st and 2nd options require me to have an instance of the component when the user is selecting one of the components to preview thus I don't think either is feasible. As for the third option, the error will be shown in the function call rather than the class definition which will be kind-of off-putting and confusing as more widget classes are made. But at-least it is something :(

Comment: @AayushSharma - You don't *need* an instance for the first one: `Example.prototype.widgetName` works. But I don't like it. The third is the closest I've gotten, but yeah, it would be better if it were an error on the `class ... extends`. I've fixed the example for that, which was a bit odd originally (need more tea).

Answer (score 1):

You can force implementing a static using an interface, but AFAIK you cannot force overriding a static (as an abstract would). Declared static functions (if any) will however override the one of their super class.

```js
interface ClassWithStaticMethod {
    staticMethod: () => void;
    new (): any;
}

const Test1: ClassWithStaticMethod = class {
    static staticMethod(){ console.log("Test.staticMethod called") }
}

const Test2: ClassWithStaticMethod = class extends Test1 {
}

const Test3: ClassWithStaticMethod = class extends Test1 {
    static staticMethod(){ console.log("Test3.staticMethod called") }
}

function callStaticMethod (AClass: ClassWithStaticMethod){
AClass.staticMethod();
}

callStaticMethod(Test1); // Test.staticMethod called
callStaticMethod(Test2); // Test.staticMethod called
callStaticMethod(Test3); // Test3.staticMethod called
```